# How to set text margin without conflict with block environment?

Tags: latex, beamer

I want to decrease the margin between the content text and the page edge. I follow the method from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354022/modifying-the-margins-of-all-slides-in-beamer by using `\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.40mm, text margin left=1.40mm}`.

However, it will make the block not centered in the slide. Thus, how do I set the text margin without influencing the setting of the block?
Is there another way to set the text margin?

The full scripts as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{structurebold} 

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multicol} 

\title[Short title]{Full Title of the Talk} 

\author{JJ XX} 
\institute[UCLA] 
{
University of California \\ 
\medskip
\textit{jx@111.com} 
}
\date{\today} 

% set the text margin
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.40mm, text margin left=1.40mm}
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{-0.2\labelsep}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Contents}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{multicols}
\end{frame}

\section{blocka}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{blocka}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First
  \item Second
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{exampleblock}{Introduction to Beamer}
    Beamer is a class of \LaTeX.
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\section{blockb}
\begin{frame}
  The second example.
  \frametitle{blockb}
  \begin{block}{Beamer Intro}
    New is New.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I wonder if you already tried `\usetheme{CambridgeUS}` instead of your custom modifications? It has narrow margins by default and uses your colour theme.

Comment: I check the theme and I also like the theme. However, their margins is the same after I check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margins of beamer blocks are designed in such a way that the text within the block is still aligned with the surrounding text. If you set the margin independently, this will break this alignment:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.40mm, text margin left=1.40mm}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{%
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \hfill\begin{minipage}{.98\textwidth}%
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=block title,lower=block body,shadow=true]%
    {\raggedright\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle}%
    \raggedright%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}
{\end{beamerboxesrounded}\end{minipage}\vskip\smallskipamount}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  The second example.
  \frametitle{blockb}
  \begin{block}{Beamer Intro}
    New is New.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, you could use the `tcolorbox` inner theme:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.40mm, text margin left=1.40mm}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  center,
  width=\linewidth
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  The second example.
  \frametitle{blockb}
  \begin{block}{Beamer Intro}
    New is New.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It could only solve the problem of block. How about the title page and the content page? The title box still too close to the left edge of page.

Comment: I use texlive 2019, thus it seem has no `tcolorbox`

Comment: TL2019 does have tcolorbox, it just lacks the tcolorbox inner theme. I only published this theme this summer, so you'll need TL2022 to use it. Alternatively you can download the sty file from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samcarter/beamertheme-tcolorbox/main/beamerinnerthemetcolorbox.sty

Comment: If you have a new question about the title page, please ask a new question. The title page does not use blocks, it directly uses beamercolorboxes, thus unrelated to a question about the margins of blocks.